# MYSql query not giving results when executed through php

Tags: php, mysql

No output is being displayed. But for some other query the code runs and not for this query. Also, this query runs fine on terminal. Please guide!!

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('servername','uname','passwd');
mysql_select_db('dbname');

$sql="select jobid from jobs where userid='xyz'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($col=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo 'jobid:' . $col['jobid'] . '</br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Although it hasn't anything to do with the question, I suggest you to use mysqli in stead of the normal mysql functions since they will be deprecated in the near future

Comment: Either no row row is returned, or your script is failing somewhere. `if (!$result) echo mysql_error();`

Comment: even error is also not getting displayed.

Comment: Code using mysqli also not running. Could it be related to permissions?                                                                                                                      <?php                                                     $mysqli=new mysqli('server','uname','passwd','database');                $query="select jobid from jobs where userid='xyz'";                   ?>

Comment: Try putting `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of the script and see if that makes a difference. If that doesn't make some sort of error appear, try doing `var_dump` on all of the variables you have there.

Comment: Thanks. I got my problem solved. It was with my connections only. I was working on one db and accessing another. But thanks for your replies.